# Find $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that $f(x)=f'(x)$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Find $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that $f(x)=f'(x)$.

I know that $f(x)$ can be $e^x$, but how to solve this mathematically? Are there any other solutions? Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f'(x)=f(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Set $g(x)=f(x)e^{-x}$. Then $g'(x)=0$, hence $f(x)=C \cdot e^{x}$ for some $C \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: How to get $f(x)=Ce^x$?

Comment: $g'=0$ so $g$ is constant, say $g(x)=C$. Therefore, $f(x)=g(x)e^{-x}=C. e^x$.

Answer (score 5):

By integrating $f'/f$, you can get to the solution $f(x) = Ce^x$. Now if you want to prove that it is the only solution, my suggestion is as follows:

Hint: Let $f$ be such a function, and let $g(x) = f(x)e^{-x}$. Now calculate $g'(x)$. Can you now prove the result?

Answer (score 3):

You have the problem
$$f'(t) = f(t)$$
$$f(0) = x_0$$
The solution you already know is 
$$f(t) = x_0e^t$$
Suppose $Y(t)$ is another solution of the same problem. Consider
$$y(t,s) = e^{(t-s)}Y(s).$$
The map $s \to y(t,s)$ is continuosly differentiable and
$$\frac{\partial y(t,s)}{\partial s} = e^{(t-s)}\frac{dY(s)}{ds} -e^{(t-s)}Y(s) = e^{t-s}Y(s) - e^{t-s}Y(s) = 0.$$

This implis that $y(t,s)$ is constant in $s$ and therefore 
$$x_0e^t = y(t,0) = y(t,t) = Y(t)$$

I hope this can help you!

Comment: Why go into partial diff. equations? It seems to be the OP is new to this stuff (otherwise he wouldn't make such an elementary question), and going into this seems to be way too advanced to her/him.

Comment: I only did it because there were other good answers and because I wanted to share this, in my opinion, elegant proof that I read some time ago. I am sorry that you don't like my comments :(

Comment: Oh, no @user67133 : I *do* like your answer. It is pretty elegant and nice. I just pointed out about the *apparent* level of the asker and his probable problems to understand it, but it is just cool and, in fact, +1 since it can help others (say, I myself :) to see things slightly different. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Simple elementary differential equation. Put $\,y=f(x)\,$ , then::

$$f'(x)=f(x)\iff \frac{dy}{dx}=y\implies \int\frac{dy}{y}=\int dx\implies$$

$$\implies \log y=x+c\implies y=e^{x+c}=Ke^x\;,\;\;K:=e^c=\text{ a constant}$$

Comment: This method leaves out the zero solution. A small remark: $y$ could be negative, so you want $\log|y|=x+c$, so then $y=\pm e^c e^x$.